# JavaScript TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null for scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, typeerror

I need to fix this but I dont know how to do it. I think it is easy but I am not good at js. But this codes work well.

```html
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function () {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("w-sticky-header").style.top = "0";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("w-sticky-header").style.top = "-50px";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

This is my sticky header js code. But it results in an alert as seen in the picture:[image: error]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], preferably in the form of a Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Well technically it means code could not find element with given id. Please check your html that it does have this element with id.

Comment: No it hasnt. But ı wont use this code at 1 page. But my js library has this code. What I want: When my library has this code and if a page dont use this, dont give me an alert.

Comment: You need to trigger Function conditionally then. I mean where you calling library initiate function you simply check using the same getElementById. Check this https://thisinterestsme.com/check-element-exists-javascript/

Comment: Mark the answer as correct and upvote please, so other with same problem can make use of it. Thnx